# AngularJS <select> DOM markup

Tags: angularjs

I'm curious when using ng-options and ng-model to set a selected item for the model why the Angular DOM markup isn't showing the correct value selected but is still displaying the correct value.

```
  $scope.myArray = [{ value: 'Yes' }, { value: 'No' }];

  $scope.cboModel.myArrayValSel = // Json pulled and value set from JS proxy call;

  <select ng-model="cboModel.myArrayValSel " ng-options="val.value as val.value for val in myArray " />
```

The DOM markup is rendering:

```
<option selected="selected" value="0" label="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="1" label="No">No</option>
```

So, if the value comes back as 'No' for the object model property it is displaying this in the dropdown accordingly in the browser but I don't understand why it is not setting the selected="selected" attribute on the second item in the array.  In this instance on

```
<option value="1" label="No">No</option>.
```

If I was just concerned with the browser output this would be more of a curiosity but I am converting the HTML to a PDF.  The PDF library is rendering the value that has the selected attribute set so there is an obvious disconnect between what is displayed in the browser and what is output in the PDF.

Comment: attributes and properties are not the same thing. Some properties will not be visible as attributes in the live html. How are you converting the html to pdf?

Comment: Right, but my curiosity is how angular is deriving the selected="selected" attribute mark up in the DOM.  I guess I was expecting that Angular would add this to the element bound to the selected item in the array ng-.model="cboModel.myArrayValSel "

Comment: Likely so that something is selected if ng-model is null.

Comment: I am converting this to PDF via a post to a Web API service.  I am using NRECO.PdfGenerator to generate the PDF resource.  I have a subsequent get request that pulls down the resource from the API.

Comment: So all you are sending is the data I would assume in which case I don't know why you would have a problem ... or what your actual problem is

Comment: I'm sending the HTML up in the body to the post request; not a JSON model.  Simply converting the entire page with an HTML to PDF generator.  Due to the size and need to store this server side this was more practical than JSPdf or some other client side converter.  If the ng-model was null I don't see how the browser is rendering it correctly.  I'm just curious on how Angular is injecting this selected="selected" attribute to the appropriate option element.

Comment: just a really bad idea to work from element attributes when it is the element properties that matter. You could process the html first to set the attributes as soon as you pull it from the DOM

Comment: No arguments here, I'm probably just trying to hard here to get away on the cheap without manipulating the DOM.

Comment: don't do it in the DOM, do it outside of the DOM

Comment: This is how at least one attribute is selected for accessibility reasons. 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8366
https://github.com/petebacondarwin/angular.js/commit/258bbce0be5d9ae9b41ced11411d65553b883479

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `selected` attribute would only effect the initial page load (based on the value assigned to `$scope.cboModel.myArrayValSel`).

If you want to see real values in the `<option>` `value` attributes, use a `track by` expression, eg

```
ng-options="val.value for val in myArray track by val.value"
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bl13bMMyO88WrCgLyo3k?p=preview)</kbd>

---

Note, for this to work, the bound `ng-model` must be an actual value from the array, not a scalar property (like `'Yes'` or `'No'`).

You'll note in my example that I have

```
$scope.choice = $scope.myArray[0];
```

Comment: Interesting. Good to know. Just curious to know why changing the initial "Yes" to "No" by selecting "No" in the drop down does not add the selected attribute to the "No" option.

Comment: To re-iterate what's already been mentioned in the comments above, attributes are different to properties

Comment: I need to read up a little more on the track by.  I'm assuming this is adding a watch under the hood to the selected value model.  This particular form has a couple hundred drop down's so I'm assuming it could lend itself to some performance concerns.

Comment: @inspiredcoder not adding a watch, just changing what is watched. The default track by uses `$index` (or `$id` or something) which is why the default values are 0, 1, etc

Comment: This really explains why the attribute is showing this way.  I went ahead and simply added an element for these values and am parsing it server side with html agility pack to get the PDF output I am looking for.  Thanks.